# Does Firebase In App Purchase could prevent crack of my App

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase

I'm wondering if Firebase could handle the IAP security for my application. In default structure of application we need to create communication to the server API. Is there anything does the Firebase could do with this structure? or Firebase would be just bridge to server. Is it secure,liable, and scalable to add virtual currency, virtual item with Firebase?

Comment: Did you ever find out?